# How to increase the speed of Socket TCP communication in C# with an external client on the same PC (host)

Tags: c#, performance, sockets

I have a SoftPLC that connects to C# via Client TCP and sends a 250 bytes packet every 100ms. The program I created in C# is working and receives these bytes, but it can only read at a rate of about 700 milliseconds per packet.
[image]
Is there a way to make this program receive packets faster, at a rate of 100 milliseconds per packet?

I'm new at C# and I used the example at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/networking/sockets/socket-services

I tried to use "listener.NoDelay = true" trying to speed up the communication, but it didn't work.

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 13001);

using Socket listener = new(
    ipEndPoint.AddressFamily,
    SocketType.Stream,
    ProtocolType.Tcp);

listener.Bind(ipEndPoint);
listener.Listen(100);
//listener.NoDelay = true;
var handler = await listener.AcceptAsync();
while (true)
{
    // Receive message.
    var buffer = new byte[1_024];
    var received = await handler.ReceiveAsync(buffer, SocketFlags.None);
    var response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, received);

    var eom = "<|EOM|>";
    if (response.IndexOf(eom) > -1 /* is end of message */)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(
            $"Socket server received message: \"{response.Replace(eom, "")}\"");
        
        //var ackMessage = "<|ACK|>";
        //var echoBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ackMessage);
        //await handler.SendAsync(echoBytes, 0);
        //Console.WriteLine(
        //    $"Socket server sent acknowledgment: \"{ackMessage}\"");

        //break;
    }
    // Sample output:
    //    Socket server received message: "Hi friends !"
    //    Socket server sent acknowledgment: "<|ACK|>"
}
```

Comment: I think you need to set the socket transmission options on the 'handler' socket, not the 'listener' socket. 'Listener' is the socket used to accept incoming connections. 'Handler' is the accepted connection

Comment: I would add a time stamp to each message (on both send and receive)  to see if the delay is on the send or receive side of the connection.  I would also run for a minute and see if the minute average is same as your short test.   We need to see the latency and if the latency is constant or varying.

Comment: Your code is assuming that one `ReceiveAsync` is one message, which is not the case. It may be a partial message or multiple messages or both. Fix this logic bug and you'll most likely find the missing messages.

Comment: BTW, many of the MS socket examples have this issue. They definitely do not represent production-ready code.

Comment: @jdweng I put a Stopwatch instruction at each communication instruction and the received = await handler.ReceiveAsync(buffer, SocketFlags.None) takes 600 ms to execute. The others take 0 ms. 
At the SoftPLC side (client), the Done of the TCP Write Block arrives each 600 ms too. But the problem is not at the SoftPLC side because the same program communicates with instruments in 14ms.

Comment: I would use a real Async method (https://gist.github.com/leandrosilva/656054).  The await is causing the issue which is blocking and being monitored using timers giving the 0/600 delay.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you cannot influence this on the receiving side of the TCP stream.

The TCP stack, which your program sends the data too, and which is responsible for putting the data on the wire, will not send the data straight away if it is a small amount of data.  It will, by default, wait a predetermined time to see if more data arrives from the sending program, before putting that data on the wire.  If no more data arrives, it will eventually put that data on the wire.  The sender can either force the TCP stack to send all data, or it can set the socket to be NoDelay and then the data will be sent immediately following every Socket.Send()

Secondly, if your client is sending messages every 100ms then you'll find that the messages are most likely being sent in a burst of traffic and that burst happens to be every 700ms.

You need to fix your Read() logic to read and process all the data that is available in the buffer.  Then you will find your missing messages.